# How to get total weight of a case size e.g. 12 x 160g equal to 1.92kg

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if this is possible.

But, let's say I have a column like this in a table:

```
12 x 60g
12 x 160g
500g
1kg
1kg
12 x 160g
12 x 250g
```

Some are are individual sizes and some are case sizes.

Is it possible to get the total weight for each row? If so, how would it be done?

e.g.

```
0.72kg  /* 12 x 0.060 = 0.72 */
1.92kg  /* 12 x 0.160 = 1.92 ... */
0.5kg
1kg
1kg
1.92kg
3kg
```

Comment: The column you have is a prime example for database misuse. It should be at least 3 separate columns: Value, Unit, Multiplier. Instead of trying to write SQL that figures out this column, try to change your database design and resolve the mushed-together data once and for all.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak - The database design was created by somebody else, and it's quite frustrating that it has been designed this way, so I totally agree with you adding these columns in. It's essentially a warehouse management system from an external company but I am using their data to create our own software to meet our needs. I'll have to contact them see if it can be changed. But in the meantime, I'll probably need to hard-code something like `WHEN reference LIKE '12 x 160' THEN 1.92`.

Comment: Probably the best-performing approach is creating a two-column helper table that resolves values like `'12 x 160g'` to `1.92`. Fill it with the `SELECT DISTINCT` from your main table and supply all the calculation results manually. Then you could join against that table and skip any in-line calculation altogether. Of course that's only viable if the values are not all over the place, but form a limited set.

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah that sound like a good approach. I'll make a start on that now, cheers for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to the comment by @Tomalak, below is an example script you could use to populate the weight expression translation table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Weights(
     Weight varchar(20) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Weights PRIMARY KEY
    ,WeightInGrams int NULL
    ,WeightInKilograms AS CAST(WeightInGrams / 1000.0 AS decimal(10, 2))
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Weights(Weight)
    SELECT DISTINCT Weight
    FROM dbo.Foo;
GO

DECLARE
      @Weight varchar(20)
    , @WeightInGrams int
    , @SqlExpression nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE foo CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT weight
    FROM dbo.Weights;
OPEN foo;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

    FETCH NEXT FROM foo INTO @Weight;

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    
    BEGIN TRY

        SET @SqlExpression = 'SET @WeightInGrams = 
            ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Weight, 'x', '*'), 'kg', '000'), 'g', '');

        EXEC sp_executesql @SqlExpression
            , N'@WeightInGrams int OUTPUT'
            , @WeightInGrams = @WeightInGrams OUTPUT;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        SET @WeightInGrams = NULL;

    END CATCH;

    UPDATE dbo.Weights
    SET WeightInGrams = @WeightInGrams
    WHERE Weight = @Weight;

END
CLOSE foo;
DEALLOCATE foo;
GO
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the advantage of using `sp_executesql` here? I would have gone with a `FOR UPDATE` cursor.

Comment: ...or with an insert query that selects any missing rows and does the calculation, coming to think of it.

Comment: @Tomalak, I used `sp_executesql` only to calculate the value. Could have used an updateable cursor too. My answer was intended as a starting point that could be extended as desired.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to check if there's anything that I'm unaware of here.

Answer (score 1):

Function to calculate kg's in flow:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.computeWeightKg(@weight NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS NUMERIC
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NUMERIC = 0; 
    DECLARE @Divider INT = 1;
    DECLARE @xIndex INT = NULL;

    IF (RIGHT(@weight, 2) = 'kg')
    BEGIN
        SET @weight = SUBSTRING(@weight, 1, LEN(@weight) - 2);
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SET @weight = SUBSTRING(@weight, 1, LEN(@weight) - 1);
        SET @Divider = 1000;
    END

    SET @xIndex = CHARINDEX('x', @weight)

    IF @xIndex = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = CAST(@weight AS NUMERIC)
    END ELSE BEGIN
        DECLARE @x1 NVARCHAR = SUBSTRING(@weight, 1, @xIndex - 1);
        DECLARE @x2 NVARCHAR = SUBSTRING(@weight, @xIndex + 2, 50);

        SET @Result = CAST(@x1 AS NUMERIC) * CAST(@x2 AS NUMERIC);
    END

    RETURN @Result / @Divider;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the format of the column will be pretty similar to what you have given, so kg or g, and a single number or two numbers separated by an `x`, and maybe having spaces:

12 x 60g
12 x 160g
500g
1kg
12 x 250g

So we can create an inline function to do all this calculation with a series of `APPLY`s.:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GetCalculatedWeight
    (@val varchar(20))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
(
SELECT
    Result = v3.FirstNum * v3.SecondNum / v2.Factor

FROM
-- Remove spaces
    (SELECT Val = REPLACE(@val, ' ', '') ) v1
-- Get division factor and position of 'x'
OUTER APPLY (SELECT
    factor = CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%kg' THEN 1 ELSE 1000 END,
    toTakeOff = CASE WHEN @val LIKE '%kg' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
    x = CHARINDEX('x', v1.Val)
) v2

OUTER APPLY (SELECT
    FirstNum = TRY_CAST(
        CASE WHEN v2.x = 0 THEN
            LEFT(v1.Val, LEN(v1.Val) - v2.toTakeOff)
        ELSE
            LEFT(v1.Val, v2.x - 1)
        END
        AS int),
    SecondNum = CASE WHEN v2.x > 0 THEN
            TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(v1.Val, v2.x + 1, LEN(v1.Val) - v2.toTakeOff - v2.x - 1) AS int)
        ELSE 1
        END
) v3

)
```

You use this by `APPLY`ing it to your table:

```sql
SELECT t.*, Weight = wt.Result
FROM table t
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetCalculatedWeight (t.Weight) wt
```

If you have decimals then replace the `TRY_CAST`s to `int` with `decimal`.