# How to return the output of a Math formula inside a SQL Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sql can do simple operations like so:

```
SELECT 5 * 5;

>> 25
```

But, let's say I have column like so, just using numbers and multiplication operator:

```
column 1
5 * 5
2 * 8
4 * 0.16
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/634da/1

How would I execute these rows, to get an output like so:

```
column 1   column 2

5 * 5         25
2 * 8         16
4 * 0.16      0.64
```

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL.  This really isn't recommended.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why not?

Comment: This is already answered here, why you posting again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65577474/how-to-get-total-weight-of-a-case-size-e-g-12-x-160g-equal-to-1-92kg

Comment: @LV98 Why? Because 5 * 5 is ALWAYS 25. There is no reason to calculate the value every time you need to access the result.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov 14.0.1000.169

Comment: @LV98 why do you want this? Never mind that you already posted a better question and accepted the answer. With dynamic SQL one could store eg `; drop table users;--` and get your program to drop a table. That's how SQL injection attacks happen

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Let's say I have a times table in a SQL column?

Comment: If you want to perform complex calculations it's better to *not* store such data at all, use separate fields instead and use formulas or calculated fields to get the derived value

Comment: @LV98 let's not say or assume anything. Ask about your actual problem and why you don't use proper fields to hold different values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't know to take out the function `EXEC sp_executesql` and apply it.. I thought I'd ask another question to see how it can be executed differently.

Comment: @LV98 you should explain what the *actual* problem is. Why store such expressions at all? Why not store individual weight, capacity, duration fields, so you can calculate whatever you want with plain SQL expressions? Or even better, why not store the *results*? Those expression aren't going to change once stored, so there's no need to evaluate them over and over

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was over complicating things, the answer from my previous question was ideal. What I did was, created a separate database and created a `Weight` table in there. Apologizes for creating a lot of misunderstanding..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Procedure/Function using `xml.query()`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STRING_TO_MATH
    @string_value nvarchar(max)
AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = N' DECLARE @x xml = '''' SELECT CAST(@x.query('''+@string_value+''') as nvarchar(max))'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Then call the procedure

```
EXEC STRING_TO_MATH '4 * 0.16' -- 0.64
```

Comment: So if the cell contains `')); drop table users; --`, this stored procedure will drop the table. This is no better than a dynamic SQL concatenating `SELECT ` with the expression

Comment: No. That is the reason i'm using `query()`. We will get `XQuery [query()]: No more tokens expected at the end of the XQuery expression` @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: That won't help at all because `@string_value` can always be adjusted to finish the the statement and execute `DROP`

Comment: That's a learning for me. :) I was under impression that this will prevent sql injection.  @PanagiotisKanavos. Could you please show me an example? So that I can convey the same to my colleagues.